# Use JSONDecoder in swift 4

Tags: arrays, json, jsondecoder

I am using swift 4 xcode 9.2, I got the below error when using JSONDecoder.

> typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], 
>              debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", 
>              underlyingError: nil))

```
class Hits: Codable { 
    let hits: [Hit] 

    init(hits: [Hit]) { 
       self.hits = hits 
    } 
}

class Hit: Codable { 
    let recipe: String 
    let uri: String 
    let label: String 
    let image: String 
    let source: String 
    let url: String 
    let shareAs: String 
    let yield: String 

    init(recipe: String, uri: String, label: String, image: String, source: String, url: String, shareAs: String, yield: String) {
        self.recipe = recipe 
        self.uri = uri 
        self.label = label 
        self.image = image 
        self.source = source 
        self.url = url 
        self.shareAs = shareAs 
        self.yield = yield
    }
}

func downloadJSON() { 
    guard let downloadURL = url else {return}   
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { (data, urlResponse, error) in 
       guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else { print("Something is wrong"); return } 
       print("download completed") 
       do { 
          let decoder = JSONDecoder() 
          let foods = try decoder.decode([Hits].self, from: data)  
          print(foods) 
       } catch { 
          print(error) 
       } 
   }.resume()
}
```

Here is the JSON:
https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=110d8671&app_key=3f01522208d512f592625dfcd163ff5c&from=0&to=10

Comment: show us your code so we can help you. i assume you have taken the wrong type (array) instead of (dictionary) when decoding...

Comment: class Hits: Codable{
    let hits: [Hit]
    
    init(hits: [Hit]){
        self.hits = hits
    }
}

Comment: class Hit: Codable{
let recipe: String
let uri: String
let label: String
let image: String
let source: String
let url: String
let shareAs: String
let yield: String
init(recipe: String, uri: String, label: String, image: String, source: String, url: String, shareAs: String, yield: String){
self.recipe = recipe
self.uri = uri
self.label = label
self.image = image
self.source = source
self.url = url
self.shareAs = shareAs
self.yield = yield

Comment: Here is the function of downloadJSON()
   func downloadJSON(){
        guard let downloadURL = url else {return}
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { (data, urlResponse, error) in guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else{
                print("Something is wrong")
                return }
        print("download completed")
            do{
  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
  let foods = try decoder.decode([Hits].self, from: data)
  print(foods)
   } catch{
           print(error)
                
            }
        }.resume()

Comment: you can edit your question -> there you can mark your code and then tap on the "parenthesis" -> then your code will be formatted nicely and we will understand it better ;)

Comment: the problem is this line:  try decoder.decode([Hits].self, from: data) print(foods) } -> you expect an array : [Hits] -> but it is an dictionary (your json)

Answer (score 2):

The error clears states that you are trying to decode an array but the actual type is a dictionary (single object).

Replace

```
let foods = try decoder.decode([Hits].self, from: data)
```

with

```
let foods = try decoder.decode(Hits.self, from: data)
```

And your classes (actually structs are sufficient) are

```
struct Recipe : Decodable {
    let uri : URL
    let label : String
    let image : URL
    let source : String
    let url : URL
    let shareAs : URL
    let yield : Double
    let calories, totalWeight, totalTime : Double
}

struct Hits: Decodable {
    let hits: [Hit]
}

struct Hit: Decodable {
    let recipe: Recipe
}
```

Comment: After that I got the error below. 
                      typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: 
                      [TestTableView.Hits.(CodingKeys in 
                    F57C5D8E25B3781A1A1D556B4F4F396A).hits, Foundation.(_JSONKey in _12768CA107A31EF2DCE034FD75B541C9)(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: Optional(0)), TestTableView.Hit.(CodingKeys in _F57C5D8E25B3781A1A1D556B4F4F396A).recipe], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: The error says that the value for `recipe` is a dictionary, in terms of Codable another struct.

Comment: You have to declare another struct or class like `Hit`

Comment: I have created another class like this.

class Hits: Codable {
    let hits: [Hit]
    
    init(hits: [Hit]) {
        self.hits = hits
    }
}

Comment: The class must be named `Recipe` and must contain properties which match the JSON keys and types. By the way all initializers are not needed if you adopt Codable.

Comment: Finally, I can get the JSON result. However, I found that all the values of the JSON result is nil. How can I do?

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing the JSON

Comment: Here is the result: 
Hit(bookmarked: nil, bought: nil, recipe: Optional(TestTableView.Recipe(calories: nil, cautions: nil, dietLabels: nil, digest: nil, healthLabels: nil, image: nil, ingredientLines: nil, ingredients: nil, label: nil, shareAs: nil, source: nil, totalTime: nil, totalWeight: nil, uri: nil, url: nil, yield: nil)))

Comment: Once again, it's impossible to answer without knowing the JSON. Basically declare properties non-optional to get errors. And please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59226649/edit) your question to add information.

Answer (score 0):

```
hits = try decoder.decode(Hits.self from: data)
```

Comment: Do I need to define hits = dict["hits"] in the swift.file?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.